# How to push an image to the Docker registry using podman

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry, podman

Is it possible to push images to the Docker registry using podman?

I am running podman with the `podman-docker` (that claims to emulate the Docker CLI)  package on fedora and I managed to successfully run `docker login` with my hub.docker.com credentials, but when I try to push an image it fails to connect.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to be more explicit than the answer above:

```
podman system prune -a
podman login -u myuser -p mypassword  docker.io/myuser/myimage
podman build -t localhost/myimage .
$ podman images
REPOSITORY                TAG            IMAGE ID      CREATED             SIZE
localhost/myimage           latest         1546573dd25d  About a minute ago  716 MB
docker.io/library/docker  19.03.12-dind  66dc2d45749a  20 months ago       227 MB

podman push 1546573dd25d docker://docker.io/myuser/myimage:1.0.0
```

Comment: I guess because you build with localhost/myimage. Why dont you tag it with myuser/myimage right away?

Answer (score 0):

I did add dockerhub to my registries.conf. Not sure if its stricly required.

```
$ cat /etc/containers/registries.conf
[registries.search]
registries = ['docker.io', 'quay.io']
```

But I can just push as you would expect with docker.

```
podman build -t myuser/myimage .
podman login -u myuser
podman push myuser/myimage
```

podman version is 3.4.2

Answer (score -1):

It was enough to specify the address of the docker registry

```
docker push imageID docker://docker.io/username/ImageName:tag
```